# Gershgorin’s Circle Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

why does Gershgorin’s Circle Theorem say that the eigenvalues of D are the diagonal elements of D?

D is a diagonal matrix with distinct real entries on the diagonal,

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the sum of each row (not including the diagonal entry) is zero.  Hence the Gershgorin disk has radius zero, i.e. is a single point.

Comment: And we might as well point out that the entries of $D$ do not need to be distinct or even real.

Comment: what do you mean "Gershgorin disk has radius zero, i.e. is a single point."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem